# Java Android how to make two parallel progress bars in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I am making a game that has a recyclerview with several items, each item has its own progressbar filling time, I need them to fill in parallel and start over after completion.

I did it with asynctask. it seems to work, but after a few fills they start working sequentially, which does not suit me.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        repository.IncrBalancePotato(positionEnd);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        new ProgressBarAsyncTask(progressBar,progressItem,positionEnd).execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: this isn't enough code to really give you an answer. `asynctask` is deprecated, you might find something else to use. furthermore, it probably isn't ideal that this code sits in your recyclerview itself, it should probably be somewhere else that keeps track of the progress of every entry and as you scroll up or down it will use that instead

Comment: what to use instead of asynctask?